# The existence of free lunch

Tags: price

Is there a free lunch or something beneficial but with zero price? Is air in an unpolluted area free lunch? If so, the sentence "there is always a tradeoff between benefit and cost" is not in general true. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of a free lunch is a philosophical/political phrase (not an axiom or law in economics). [It was popularized by Nobel Prize winning economist Milton Friendman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_ain%27t_no_such_thing_as_a_free_lunch)

The concept depends too largely on how you define *free* to make a general statement about the concept. For example, while Oxygen is readily available for your consumption from the atmosphere at a *cost* of zero, Friedman argued there was always an opportunity cost involved (you could be breathing ultra-pure oxygen from an oxygen tank to avoid pollutants in the atmosphere that will give you cancer) so technically there is a cost.

Comment: Good point quoting the Friedman argument. I was thinking about opportunity cost but for some dumb reason, did not come up with an example that convinced myself.